# Alpine.js - stop video on modal close

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a working code, that stops the video on modal close. However, I wonder is there a way to achieve the same results using Alpine.js only. Without having a separate JS  as in my current case.

Here is my code:

```
<div x-show="videoModal">
  <div @click.away="videoModal = false, handleClick(videoPlayer)">
    <div id="videoPlayer">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $video_id }}"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function handleClick(element) {
    var iframe = element.querySelector( 'iframe');
    if ( iframe ) {
      var iframeSrc = iframe.src;
      iframe.src = iframeSrc;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an `x-ref` on your iframe element and define your `handleClick` method inside Alpine directly:

```js
<div x-show="videoModal" x-data="{
  handleClick() {
    this.videoModal = false;
    const iframeElement = this.$refs.iframe;
    if (iframeElement) {
      const iframeSrc = iframeElement.src;
      iframeElement.src = iframeSrc;
    }
  }
}">
  <div @click.away="handleClick()">
    <div id="videoPlayer">
      <iframe x-ref="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $video_id }}"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```